# Add recordHeatRangeActivity to blCheckoutWorkflowActivities

Tags: broadleaf-commerce

I'm trying Order Submit Workflow For Heat Clinic Tutorial. I can't add a new activity `recordHeatRangeActivity` to `blCheckoutWorkflowActivities`:  where is the `applicationContext` file? Should I create this file? Where is the java config file on which I have to append the following:

```
@Merge("blCheckoutWorkflowActivities")
public List<?> customCheckoutActivities(RecordHeatRangeActivity recordHeatRangeActivity) {
    return Arrays.asList(recordHeatRangeActivity);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How you add the activity depends on what version of BLC you have. In 5.1 and below, you will need to add the activity through an applicationContext.xml. In 5.2+, you can add this using Java Config instead. Since the `blCheckoutWorkflowActivities` bean is defined in BLC's `core` module [here](https://github.com/BroadleafCommerce/BroadleafCommerce/blob/667b0497cf18db6c8d12a0da84a1a402f6b98b59/core/broadleaf-framework/src/main/resources/bl-framework-applicationContext-workflow.xml#L202), you should add your new activity to your own project's `core` module.  You would add the method you mentioned in your question above to CoreConfig.java. Really you could add this to any class annotated with `@Configuration`.

For more information on applicationContext and Java Config, see here: https://www.broadleafcommerce.com/docs/core/current/release-notes/5.2.0-ga#removal-of-the-broadleaf-xml-merge-process